# Is it possible to append information to a structure inside of a json file without first reading it into memory?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to store a big list of lists in a json file. The lists are generated from a long running process, so I'd like to add the newly generated information into my json file as it becomes available.

Currently, in order to extend the data structure, I'm reading the json into memory as a Python list, appending the new data to that list, and then writing over the old data in the json file with the newly created list.

```
def update_json_file(new_data):
    with open('mycoolfile.json', 'rb') as f: 
        jsondata = json.load(f)

    jsondata.append(new_data)
    with open('mycoolfile.json', 'wb') as f: 
        json.dump(jsondata, f)
```

Is there a better way than reading everything into memory? Surely as the file size grows this will no longer be a viable strategy. Is there a simple way to extend a structure inside of a json file?

Comment: You can't insert data into the middle of a file, period. Use a database of some sort if you want to do this efficiently.

Comment: I would agree with the database comment above. sqlite is extremely easy to use from python. When the json file is needed it can be constructed on demand.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton Alright. Thanks for the tip. Looks like it's time for me to finally learn how databases work! I'll check out sqlite

Comment: @ZackYoshyaro is there any reason in particular that you're storing data in a json file? Is it used by another program or service? It'd be possible just to write a string to the end of the file - but you'd need to be very very careful when doing so to ensure the json structure is maintained. If it doesn't have to be a json file, then yeah, go the database route. Good luck.

Comment: @millimoose but he does not need to insert data into the middle of a file. He needs to append to the end of file. He can rewrite last ']' with comma, write `new_data` to file from this position, and finish with ']'. That should give correct json in his case. However, I whould agree that database is better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, as zaquest said, you can seek to almost the end of the file and overwrite the final ']' of the outer list. Here's something that shows how that might be done:

```
import json
import os

def append_list(json_filename, new_data):
    with open(json_filename, 'r+b') as f:
        f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
        new_json = json.dumps(new_data)
        f.write(', ' + new_json + ']')

# create a test file
lists = [
    'This is the first list'.split(),
    "and here's another.".split(),
    [10, 2, 4],
]

with open('mycoolfile.json', 'wb') as f:
    json.dump(lists, f)

append_list('mycoolfile.json', 'New data.'.split())

with open('mycoolfile.json', 'rb') as f:
    jsondata = json.load(f)
    print json.dumps(jsondata, indent=4)
```

Output:

```
[
    [
        "This",
        "is",
        "the",
        "first",
        "list"
    ],
    [
        "and",
        "here's",
        "another."
    ],
    [
        10,
        2,
        4
    ],
    [
        "New",
        "data."
    ]
]
```